# Call method on Directive to pass data to Controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So basically I have a controller, which lists a bunch of items.

Each item is rendering a directive.

Each directive has the ability to make a selection.

What I want to achieve is once the selection has been made, I want to call a method on the controller to pass in the selection.

What I have so far is along the lines of...

```
app.directive('searchFilterLookup', ['SearchFilterService', function (SearchFilterService) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: '/Areas/Library/Content/js/views/search-filter-lookup.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            setCriteria: '&'
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.showOptions = false;
            $scope.selection = [];
            $scope.options = [];

            $scope.selectOption = function(option) {
                $scope.selection.push(option);
                $scope.setCriteria(option);
            };
        }
    };

}]);
```

The directive is used like this:

```
<div search-filter-lookup model="customField" criteria="updateCriteria(criteria)"></div>
```

Then the controller has a function defined:

```
$scope.updateCriteria = function(criteria) {
    console.log("Weeeee");
    console.log(criteria);
};
```

The function gets called fine. But I'm unable to pass data to it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$scope.setCriteria({criteria: option});
```

When you declare an isolated scope "&" property, angular parses the expression to a function that would be evaluated against the parent scope.

when invoking this function you can pass a locals object which extends the parent scope.

It's a common mistake to think that `$scope.setCriteria` is the same as the function inside the attribute. If you log it you'll see it's just an angular parsed expression function which have the parent scope saved at it's closure.

So when you run `$scope.setCriteria()` you actually evaluate an expression against the parent scope.
In your case this expression happens to be a function but it could be any expression.

But you don't have a `criteria` property on the parent scope, that's why angular let you pass a locals object to extend the parent scope. e.g. `{criteria: option}`

#### Extends the parent scope

you wrote in a comment that it requires the directive to have knowledge of the parameter name defined in the controller. No it doesn't, it just extends the parent scope with a `criteria` option, you can still use any expression you want though you are provided with an extra property you may use.

A good example would be `ngEvents`, take `ng-click="doSomething($event)"`:

`ngClick` provides you with a local property `$event`, you don't have to use but you may if you need.

the directive doesn't know anything about the controller, it's up to you to decide which expression you write, cheers.

Comment: Ah huh! That works. But it requires the directive to have knowledge of the parameter name defined in the controller. Is there a way to avoid this? Or should there be a standard naming convention for this?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the function in using `=`...

```
scope: {
    model: '=',
    setCriteria: '='
},
controller: function($scope) {
    // ...

    $scope.selectOption = function(option) {
        $scope.selection.push(option);
        $scope.setCriteria(option);
    };
}

<div search-filter-lookup model="customField" criteria="updateCriteria"></div>
```